# Rewrite conditional statement

Tags: php

I have this if else block code

```
 if($_POST["item"]=="All"){
        $notificatioSetting->AllNotification=$_POST["status"];
    }
    else if($_POST["item"]=="Accept"){
        $notificatioSetting->AcceptTrackRequest=$_POST["status"];
    }
    else if($_POST["item"]=="Deny"){
        $notificatioSetting->DenyTrackRequest=$_POST["status"];
    }
```

this condition continues for almost 12 another else if condition. Beside this and switch, is there a better way?

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review.

Comment: I would recommend the use of `isset()` upon the lookup array, instead of what is provided in the answer below, but alas, the page is closed so I cannot show/explain.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a lot of conditions I recommend you to use an HashMap (associative array in php) to store the conditions, like this :

```
$notificationsItems = [
    "All" => "AllNotification",
    "Accept" => "AcceptTrackRequest",
    "Deny" => "DenyTrackRequest"
];
```

When you have your pair, you can test all the conditions through a simple foreach:

```
foreach ($notificationsItems as $postValue => $objectAttr) {
    if ($_POST["item"] == $postValue) {
        $notificatioSetting->{$objectAttr} = $_POST["status"];
        break; //we make an early termination
    }
}
```

This version mimic exactly the `elseif`code. As itzmukeshy7 put in his response, there is a solution with fewer lines of code :

```
if(in_array($_POST["item"], $notificationsItems)) {
    $notificationSetting->{$notificationsItems[$_POST["item"]]} = $_POST["status"];
}
```

In this way adding more conditions will be really easy while making the code more extensible and more decoupled. In addition you'll make explicit the association between a post value and the corresponding attribute in the object, which is good for your futur self or colleague(s).